# insert into table from two another tables - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 3 tables. Two First tables has data and i want 3rd table insert data from that first two.

**TABLE A :**

```
CREATE TABLE z_ostan ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                     name  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL CHECK (upper(name)=name) 
                     );
```

**TABLE B:**

```
CREATE TABLE z_shahr ( id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                     name  VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL CHECK (upper(name)=name),
                     ref_ostan NUMBER,
                     CONSTRAINT fk_ref_ostan FOREIGN KEY (ref_ostan) REFERENCES z_ostan(id)
                    );
```

**TABLE C**:

```
CREATE TABLE z_shar2 ( shahr_name VARCHAR2(30),
                       ostan_name VARCHAR2(30),
                       payetakht number);
```

*insert data from TABLE A and B into C by this conditions:*

- `shahr_name`  in TABLE C comes from `z_shahr.name` in TABLE B
- `ostan_name`  in TABLE C comes from `z_ostan .name` in TABLE A
- and `payetakht` has two mode:

  - default null else
  - if ostan_name is 'somthing' then =1

**i CANT INSERT BY This Conditions on TABLE C**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a join:

```
INSERT INTO z_shar2 (shahr_name, ostan_name, payetakht)
   SELECT b.name,
          a.name,
          CASE WHEN a.name = 'somthing' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END payetakht
     FROM z_shahr b JOIN z_ostan a ON a.id = b.ref_ostan
```

As of `payetakht` column's value: I initially thought that you, actually, meant `when a.name is not null` but that can't be as `name` column is declared as `not null`, so ... that's probably really (misspelled) *somthing*.